# purrr and ggplot function are not displaying plot (NSE issue)

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr, nse

I suspect this is a problem dealing with NSE. But why isn't these two approaches work and how can I get them to work.

```
temp1 <- function(x){
  iris %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(as.formula(paste("~", x)))
}
walk('Species', temp1)


temp2 <- function(x){
  x <- as.name(x)
  iris %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ x)
}
walk('Species', temp2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it doesn't appear to be an NSE issue. If you read `?walk` it says (emphasis added by me):

> walk() calls .f for its side-effect and **returns the original input**

Try:

```
t <- walk('Species', temp1)
t
#[1] "Species"
```

I think you can get what you want if you add an explicit print to your `ggplot`. E.g. change `temp1` to be:

```
temp1 <- function(x){
  print(iris %>% 
        ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_wrap(as.formula(paste("~", x))))
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Can you comment on why doing it (alternatively) via piping does not work. That is `... %>% print()`.

Comment: @student, because if you use a simple piping, you'll pass the `facet_wrap()` object to `print`. If you want to pipe, you could group the whole thing with `()` and then pass it to `print`. Something like `(iris %>% ...) %>% print()`